# CSS @Import media query fallback

Tags: css

Is there a way to import a css file if the rule is met otherwise use another so that in anycase one of the two files will be used and only one of them.

Somthing like:

@import "dark.css" screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark);
**else** @import "default.css";

Currently I'm doing this with with JavaScript, just curious if there is a pure css way

Answer (score 0):

CSS DOESN'T has conditionals. So you can't do that "else".

But you can do an import for the default and then, override the CSS values by importing dark.css

```
@import "default.css" screen;
@import "dark.css" screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark);
```

Comment: But actually both are imported so if you have some default mode rules that is not overridden in the dark.css it will also be taken.

Comment: If you don't want to actually load the .css classes and that is what you're looking for, then, as you said, JS should be used to dynamically import the files. But, I do not suggest you that, because if a user wants to switch to "dark mode" then, it starts to download the new .css file just for that, while if you do it from the beginning then you can simply do the switch and that's it. By the way, just add the critical CSS at the beggining so you don't block anything and then load default and dark with defer and not worrying about anything :)

Comment: well you could just load both and then disable the one you don't need and add a listener to detect changes

Comment: Me? why me? :S ...I think you're talking about "you" :S ...but I will suppose that you're talking about "you" and this case. So, no, that should not work like that AT ALL because that is not how it should works, because technically CSS can't emit events or receive events, it only works for styles. You're mixing things.

Comment: Hmm Sorry for confuse you,  I'm anserwing this part about how one can do it with js. ->
But, I do not suggest you that, because if a user wants to switch to "dark mode" then, it starts to download the new .css file just for that, while if you do it from the beginning then you can simply do the switch and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no if/else in pure `CSS`. You must use the javascript function to do this. Alternative there are `CSS` preprocessors like Sass, you can use. You can read more about it here: [Sass conditonals](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control).